# GMP- Power without modulo

Tags: c++, c, gmp

I am trying to raise and arbitrarily larger number to an arbitrarily large power. As far as I can see, GMP has a function that does this, but applies modulo to the result, and a function that lets me raise an arbitrary number to an `unsigned int` exponent. Is there a way around this?

Comment: May be you can use log functions to calculate. Making sure that you don't overflow the variable. http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/math.h/log.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and a function that lets me raise an arbitrary number to an `unsigned int` exponent

It's an `unsigned long int` exponent, so if you are on a system where `unsigned long` is 64 bits (or more), that will take you beyond the available memory for the next few years (`2^(2^64-1)` needs a couple of Exabytes storage).

If you're on a system with 32-bit `unsigned long`, you can split the exponent in two parts,

```
if (exponent >= (1u << 31)) {
    mpz_pow_ui(base, base, exponent >> 31);
    mpz_pow_ui(base, base, 1u << 31);
}
mpz_pow_ui(base, base, exponent & ((1u << 31) - 1));
```

and that has very good chances of needing more memory than you have.

A further problem is that GMP uses `int`s to count the limbs, so typically you can't have numbers using more than `(2^31 - 1)*BITS_PER_LIMB` bits anyway (`BITS_PER_LIMB` is 32 or 64 depending on the platform, usually).

If you think you need `a^b` where `a > 1` and `b` doesn't fit in an `unsigned long (long)`, you will have problems with GMP and your memory anyway.

Comment: So basically, GMP isn't powerful enough to express such large values, even if it had infinite memory to work with. Thanks.

Comment: Right (for the time being, GMP could switch to using a 64-bit type for the limb-count any time). But you're running into the memory-barrier whichever library you use.

Comment: Why should GMP support numbers that are too big to fit in the memory of any computer in the world?

Comment: @brianbeuning `2^31` limbs (I ignore the `-1`) make `2^36` or `2^37` _bits_, that's `2^33` or `2^34` bytes, 8 or 16 GB. There are already boxes around (not supercomputers!) with 128GB of RAM, probably more. Those could actually calculate with such numbers. So these years we have the transition from GMP's bignums being memory-limited to being datatype-limited. Switching to a 64-bit type for the limb count could therefore make sense.

Comment: I was just about to ask a similar question and I'm glad I found the answer here first. I hadn't done the preliminary math before seeking an answer.

Answer (score 3):

By raising a very large number to a very large power, you get a **very large number of digits**.

Possibly more digits than there's room for in the computer's memory.

For example, this laptop has a 6 GB main memory, which means 6*2^30 bits. Now if you raise (2^10) to the (2^10)'th power, you get 2^(10*(2^10)) = 2^10240. That's like many times more than 6*2^30.

In short, there's no way around if you want an exact answer for the general case.

For particular cases you may however be able to express the answer as e.g. a clean power such as 2^10240, but this means using either just human brains or an **computer algebra system** such as e.g. Macsyma or Matehmatica (I'm not sure of the names of all these, but google it).

Comment: I am aware of this. I am computing a particular transcendental number to arbitrary precision, and at some point, at least theoretically, I will be working with numbers of this magnitude. I would like to at least be able to claim that with infinite memory and infinite time my program would be able to compute the number fully. I am also aware that GMP may not be able to make this possible.